# Cannot find module jest.js

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have just installed jest (`npm install jest --save-dev`) and not changed any default settings, but can't run my tests.

`C:\Foo\Boo` - my app folder, where `app.js` and `app.test.js` files are placed.

The standard command `npm run test` results in such error:

```
> vision@1.0.0 test C:\Foo\Boo
> jest

'Boo\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Foo\jest\bin\jest.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vision@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vision@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

A bizarre thing is `Cannot find module 'C:\Foo\jest\bin\jest.js'`. It seemingly trys to find `C:\Foo\Boo\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: whether you tried with the answers in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863312/jest-gives-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths