# Jest not finding root after upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

I upgraded my project to Angular 13 and jest needed some changes too.

Now any reference to 'src' can not be resolved.

For example:

```
Cannot find module 'src/app/app.component/app.component.test' from 'src/dashboard/reports/modules/tables/matrix-table/matrix-table.test.ts'
```

This is my jest.config.js

```
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.test.json');
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');

module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  testMatch: ["**/*.test.ts"],
  coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover", "cobertura"],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.test.json"
    }
  }
};
```

What should I change in my jest config in order for it to resolve the root to src?

Comment: There are several new config options missing. The [jest-preset-angular migration guide](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/angular-13+/) and [ts-jest ESM support doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/#use-esm-presets) were really helpful with this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to hint at Typescript and Jest builder not transpiling the tests to ESM, a recent change with the Angular v13 upgrade. From the [ts-jest ESM support doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/):

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
"moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
]
```

to your jest.config.js

[This looks like a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863312/jest-gives-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths)