# How do I import from a relative path like "/utils" within my "src" folder in Jest + RTL Tests

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am creating tests with Jest and React Testing Library and I am having difficulties with imports to the `util` folder that exists within the `src` folder. I am using TypeScript for this which seems to create its own interesting challenges.

My `jest.config.ts` file looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
    'preset': 'ts-jest',
    'testEnvironment': 'node',
    'testPathIgnorePatterns': [
        '<rootDir>/dist'
    ],
    'moduleNameMapper': { 'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1' }
};
```

The test looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import { Tag } from '/components';

describe('Tabs Component', () => {
    it('should render a tab component correctly', () => {
        render(<Tag id="test" />);

        expect(screen.getAllByTestId('test')).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

When I run this I am getting import issues:

```
Cannot find module '/components' from 'src/components/Tag/Tag.spec.tsx'
```

Additionally my tsconfig looks like the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "/*": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        "outDir": "./tested/esm",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2016",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}",
        "./jest.config.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "./src/**/*.stories.tsx",
        "./*.js"
    ]
}
```

I have tried a few of the tricks from Stack Overflow like:

[Jest gives `Cannot find module` when importing components with absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863312/jest-gives-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths)

None of these seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest + Typescript + Absolute paths (baseUrl) gives error: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171412/jest-typescript-absolute-paths-baseurl-gives-error-cannot-find-module)

Comment: [Google gives a ton of answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jest+absolute+imports), are you sure you prefer waiting for someone to answer and not simply googling it and solve it in [5 minutes](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/lmnsdtce3y-import-absolute-paths-in-typescript-jest-tests)?

Comment: [Official Jest guide for absolute paths](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring)

Comment: Just the kind of response I would expect on stack overflow but I have actually tried all of those and none of them have worked for me. I tried those well before posting here.

Comment: yeah you know, it's always good to ask if OP googled or not and even **better** for OP to say so :)

Comment: You can try to create a minimal *codesandbox* demo with a single test so we could inspect the complete configuration.

Comment: " have tried a few of the tricks from Stack Overflow like:" was my way of communicating that I have done some previous searching

Comment: But Josh, I could have helped you hours ago if you would have just helped me help you by putting a *codesandbox* demo... Your question will only get pushed to the bottom of the queue if you don't act *quickly*. You might get an answer weeks or months in the future without being super active with your question and doing the maximum to assist us and solve this ASAP

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is how the `import` is done. As the `jest.config.ts` has already specified the `moduleNameMapper` as `{ 'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1' }`, it means if `Tag` component is imported as below,

```js
import { Tag } from "src/components";
```

Jest will look into the `<rootDir>/src/components/index.ts` to import the `Tag` component.

If you want to import modules in this way,

```js
import { Tag } from "components"; // not "/components"
```

It's better to replace `moduleNameMapper` config with `moduleDirectories`:

```js
module.exports = {
    'preset': 'ts-jest',
    'testEnvironment': 'node',
    'testPathIgnorePatterns': [
        '<rootDir>/dist'
    ],
    'moduleDirectories': ['node_modules', 'src']
};
```

This tells Jest when it sees an import from `"components"`, it will look into both `node_modules` and `src` and see if there is the file `components/index.ts` or `components.ts`.

PS: `tsconfig.json` is only used by the editor. Therefore, Jest won't take it into consideration. `jest.config.ts` is the config file that matters to Jest.