# How to define custom TS paths for Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a monorepo with multiple apps (Angular and NestJS) and they share some things like interfaces, enums, etc.  The apps work, and the Jasmine tests with the Angular apps work, but my Jest tests in the NestJS app are failing to import anything from the shared monorepo folder.

Here is my folder structure:

```
my-repo/
├── ng-ui-1/
├── ng-ui-2/
├── nest-api/
│   ├── src/ (folder w/ app code)
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   ├── (etc...)
├── monorepo-shared/
│   ├── enums/
│   │   ├── *.enum.ts files
│   ├── interfaces/
│   │   ├── *.interface.ts files
```

In all the typescript apps I've added this to my `tsconfig.json` files, and it works just fine

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "paths": {
      "@monorepo-shared/constants": ["../monorepo-shared/constants/index"],
      "@monorepo-shared/enums":     ["../monorepo-shared/enums/index"],
      "@monorepo-shared/interfaces":["../monorepo-shared/interfaces/index"]
    }
  }
}
```

Within a TS file I can just add this to import something from these shared folders, again this works fine everywhere except for Jest tests.

```ts
import { BrandingTypeEnum } from '@monorepo-shared/enums';
```

When I run my Jest tests I get this error

```
Cannot find module '@monorepo-shared/enums' from 'account/account.controller.spec.ts'
```

In my `package.json` I define my Jest settings.  I know I need to somehow point it towards what `@monorepo-shared/enums` is since it's not able to infer that for some reason, but everything I've tried so far hasn't been right.

```json
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "@monorepo-shared/constants",
    "@monorepo-shared/enums",
    "@monorepo-shared/interfaces",
  ],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
},
```

I've tried many of [the solutions in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863312/jest-gives-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths) and nothing has been right so far. **What do I need to change to get Jest to see these paths I've defined in my `tsconfig.json` file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jest's [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) to tell jest how to resolve `@monorepo-shared/enums` with respect to the `rootDir`. Something like this should do it

```json
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "@monorepo-shared/constants",
    "@monorepo-shared/enums",
    "@monorepo-shared/interfaces",
  ],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@monorepo-shared/enums": ["<rootDir>/../../monorepo-shared/enums/index"],
    "@monorepo-shared/constants": ["<rootDir>/../../monorepo-shared/constants/index"],
    "@monorepo-shared/interfaces":["<rootDir>/../../monorepo-shared/interfaces/index"]
  }
},
```

Comment: That's it, thank you!